# How many different functions are there from Bool to Bool?

Tags: functional-programming, boolean-logic, category-theory

Since this is (at least it seems to me) tightly related to programming, I'm asking here rather than on [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), but if you it think it best fits there or in another side, please just give your opinion.

At the end of Chapter 2 of Bartosz Milewski's *Category Theory for Programmers*, there's this question:

> How many different functions are there from `Bool` to `Bool`? Can you implement them all?

This is my reasoning:

- `Bool` has only two elements in it, `True` and `False`;
- *different* refers to what the functions do if considered blackboxes, regardless of what happens within them (for instance, two functions coding the sum of two `Int`s as `arg1 + arg2` and `arg2 + arg1` respectively, would be the same function from `Int` to `Int`);
- so the different functions are those going from one of the two `Bool`s to another of the two `Bool`s:

  1. `T` to `T`
  2. `T` to `F`
  3. `F` to `T`
  4. `F` to `F`
- What functions do I need to make those in-out scenarii possible? Well, I think I need only two, for instance the identity function, which would allow 1 and 4, and the negation, which would allow 2 and 3.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: You can still use two functions that are different from identity and negation but would still cover everything. One function only returns `T` and covers 1. + 3. the other only only returns `F` and covers 2. + 4.

Comment: I thought of that too, indeed, but based on the answer I got, it seems a wrong conclusion as well.

Comment: 1. return false. 2. return true. 3. return the input. 4. return the input negation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the different functions are those going from one of the two `Bool`s to another of the two `Bool`s

No. A function does map **every** value from its [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) to one value from its codomain. You need to consider all possible combinations of mappings. For this, it might make sense to look at the function as a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation), and list them all:

- `f -> f`, `t -> f`
- `f -> f`, `t -> t`
- `f -> t`, `t -> f`
- `f -> t`, `t -> t`

These correspond to the 4 functions

- `x => f` (constant false)
- `x => x` (identity)
- `x => not(x)` (negation)
- `x => t` (constant true)

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you asked on Programming, rather than math or CS, is important.

On Math, they'd tell you there are four such functions, listed by the other answers.

On CS, they'd tell you there are 27: one for each of three possible inputs T F and ⊥ to each of three possible outputs T F and ⊥.

Here in programming, I can tell you there are eleven:

- (T->T, F->F, ⊥->⊥) identity
- (T->F, F->T, ⊥->⊥) not
- (T->T, F->T, ⊥->T) lazy constant true
- (T->F, F->F, ⊥->F) lazy constant false
- (T->T, F->T, ⊥->⊥) strict constant true
- (T->F, F->F, ⊥->⊥) strict constant false
- (T->⊥, F->F, ⊥->⊥) identity fail on true
- (T->T, F->⊥, ⊥->⊥) identity fail on false
- (T->⊥, F->T, ⊥->⊥) not fail on true
- (T->F, F->⊥, ⊥->⊥) not fail on false
- (T->⊥, F->⊥, ⊥->⊥) fail

(This answer is quite tongue-in-cheek: I think in reality most scholarly CS types would say either 4 or 11.)

Comment: Can you explain the discrepancy you associate to the answer you think a Math, CS, and programming person would give? Maybe I can find myself that a math person would say there's no other possible value for a bool than true or false, which gives 4 combinations. But what makes the 27 and 11 scenarios different?

Comment: Basically in math (and total programming, which, tbf, probably includes the book the OP is working from) Bool only has two values. But in programming, we don't work with functions per se, we work with computations. And computations can fail to return (cf the halting problem), so in denotational semantics Bool has a third value, bottom, to represent nontermination or other failure. There are 27 functions from a three-value set to a three-value set. But of course that's still not all, because a function that returns something when its argument is bottom *does not exist*, unless it is lazy...

Comment: ...and ignores them entirely. This eliminates a bunch of the possible functions/computations, like T->F F->T bottom->T, leaving only 11. The 27 was mostly a joke; real computer scientists would of course notice that most of the three state functions cannot be computed, and eliminate them, since computation is what we added bottom to account for in the first place. (Tldr: it's mostly a joke, the answer your book is looking for is "4", as the other answers say.)

Answer (score 2):

There are four functions:

## 1

false -> false
true -> false

## 2

false -> false
true -> true

## 3

false -> true
true -> false

## 4

false -> true
true -> true

## Explanation

Your reasoning is mostly correct. The functions are blackboxes, we view them as values. Since the input is a boolean and has two possible values and the function might have two separate values, basically the number if 2^2 = 4