# All arrows in a category only containing Bool Unit and Void

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory, purely-functional

It's actually the challenge #6 from Category Theory for Programmers - [Chapter 2](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/11/24/types-and-functions/), and this question is a follow up on [this other question I asked some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63863605/5825294):

> Draw a picture of a category whose only objects are the types `Void`, `()` (unit), and `Bool`; with arrows corresponding to all possible functions between these types. Label the arrows with the names of the functions.

So this is the list of arrows/functions connecting those three objects/types which I'm more sure about:

- [4 functions `Bool -> Bool`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63863833/5825294)
- `true = const True :: () -> Bool`
- `false = const False :: () -> Bool`
- `ignore = const () :: Bool -> ()`
- `absurd :: Void -> ()`
- `absurd :: Void -> Bool`
- `id :: () -> ()`
- `id :: Void -> Void` must exist because we are talking about a category, right?
- there's nothing going to `Void` from the other two because it is an initial object, right?

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: Sounds right to me. (`id :: Void -> Void` being the same as `absurd`, incidentally.)

Comment: Note that, in general, you can have morphisms to an initial object. Initial objects in which you can't (at least up to isomorphism) are called [strict initial objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+initial+object), which is the case for `Void`.

Comment: I've actually just added `id :: () -> ()`, which I forgot.

Comment: In Set theory (and in general when Haskell types are considered as sets ignoring the bottom elements), the number of functions of type `A -> B` is equivalent to `|B|^|A|`, keeping in mind `0^0 = 1`. That's a good way to know how many functions there are between any two sets. Your listing follows this, and is correct: `|Void| = 0`, `|Unit| = 1`, and `|Bool| = 2`.

Comment: @alias That should be an answer